# Installing PyQt4 as non-root

Tags: python, pyqt, installation

Machine : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)

I am trying to install `PyQt4` for python `2.6.6` .Downloaded its [source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.9.5/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.9.5.tar.gz) from sourceforge.

I would have installed it using following commands.

```
python configure.py
make && make install
```

But my problem is that I dont have the root access.How can I install PyQt4 as not-root user ?

Answer (score 1):

If you type `python configure.py --help`, you'll get several options:

```
...
  Installation:
    -b DIR, --bindir=DIR
                        where pyuic4, pyrcc4 and pylupdate4 will be installed
                        [default: /usr/bin]
    -d DIR, --destdir=DIR
                        where the PyQt4 Python package will be installed
                        [default: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages]
    -p DIR, --plugin-destdir=DIR
                        where any plugins will be installed [default:
                        QTDIR/plugins]
    --no-sip-files      disable the installation of the .sip files [default:
                        enabled]
    -v DIR, --sipdir=DIR
                        where the PyQt4 .sip files will be installed [default:
                        /usr/share/sip]
...
```

Use the `-b`, `-d`, `-p` and `-v` options when running `configure.py` to specify target directories you have write access to.